# Difference between a stochastic environment and non-deterministic environment

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have been reading AIMA by Russell and Norvig, where they talk about different types of environments an agent may encounter. Here, they have described stochastic and non-deterministic environments being different types of environments.

> One final note: our use of the word "stochastic" generally implies that uncertainty about outcomes is quantified in terms of probabilities; a **nondeterministic** environment is one in which actions are characterized by their *possible* outcomes, but no probabilities are attached to them.

I did not understand this line, taken from the book. I'm also thinking about other possible differences between these two types of environments, and their respective real-life examples. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A stochastic situation is like when you throw a fair coin. You know the probabilities of the outcomes. You may often assume that the distribution remains constant, let alone is known.

A non-deterministic situation is when you sit in front of a black box that may turn on a green or red light and you have no idea what will happen, but you need to be prepared to either outcomes.